# how to set alpha to fragment dynamically

Tags: android

I have an activity and 8 fragment in it. I want to set 50% alpha to one my fragments dynamically, when user click button .But it seems there is no alpha attribute for fragment.
My main questions is "**how to st alpha or visibility dynamically** "
any help will be appreciated thanks
i can set visibility by this code but its not perfect

```
this.findViewById(R.id.fragment1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and can i cast fragment like view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
   .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)
   .getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

> But it seems there is no alpha attribute for fragment

That is because a fragment is not a `View`. Neither fragments, nor activities, nor strings have alpha attributes.

> how to st alpha or visibility dynamically

Call `setAlpha()` or `setVisibility()` on the `View` that is managed by the fragment. You can get this `View` by calling `getView()` on the `Fragment`, any time after `onCreateView()` has been called.